# PHP Curl Cannot Connect to Host on Own Server

Tags: php, apache, curl, apache2

I have a PHP script that uses cURL to access a file also located on my server (installed email marketing program). I wrote a quick script to test my cURL installation and it fails when pointed at a file on my own server. The script is:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mysite.com/test.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$contents = curl_exec($ch);

if($contents) {
    echo $contents;
} else {
    $err = curl_error($ch);
    echo $err;
}

curl_close($ch);
```

When I run this code, it returns an error: *couldn't connect to host*

If I change the URL to *http://www.google.com* or any other site, it works just fine. Also, when I try to open the specific page via cURL on another server, it works like it should. The assumptions I'm making from these tests is that the PHP cURL is installed and (kinda) working and that the problem is not in the page that is trying to be opened.

I thought it might be a port issue, so I tried specifying the port with the same result (not connecting to host). I tried both `curl_setopt` and `http://www.mysite.com:80/` to specify a port I know to be open.

This leads me to believe that the issue is something in my apache installation, but I'm not an apache expert and I've been banging my head against Google all day to no avail. Any ideas what could cause such a specific cURL failure?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have exactly the same problem, a script on my own server works fine when I access via the browser, but when I run cURL to access it from a subdomain it fails with error 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open `http://www.mysite.com/test.php` in a web browser.  If it works, then the problem is with cURL.  If it doesn't, then the problem is either with your network, or apache configuration.

You can check your apache configuration by making sure that it is running on your system.  Then try to `telnet <apache server ip> 80` from the command line.  Once connected try to do the following:

```
GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mysite.com
<2 line breaks>
```

If you get a response from apache, then it sounds like a network issue.  Make sure mysite.com resolves to the IP address of your apache server, and port 80 traffic can get to your server.  It could also be a loopback routing issue of your router trying to make a request to it's own ip address (assuming your apache box is behind a routed network connection, the same connection that you are on).

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same issue where my domain name would not resolve on the server causing `CURL` requests to itself to fail.

My problem was that my web server could not resolve to itself due to some firewall rules (there is a load balancer in front of the web server that was blocking traffic from the server).

In other words, running the following command on my server

`curl -I http://www.mywebserver.com` resulted in:

`$ curl -I http://www.mywebserver.com
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`

Updating the /etc/hosts file on the server to map the domain name to the  local ip address resolved the issue and `fopen` and `curl` from within my scripts were functional again.

Comment: I know this question was some time ago but I wanted to give you an upvote as this was the solution that worked for me after a day of hair pulling.

Comment: thank you so much, after a long time this is what worked for me too.
I was having cURL timeout on wordpress every time it tried to access the api but query monitor was saying it was some kind of ssl error, although i could curl https urls from the terminal. Then I decided to try my own domain and it also timed out, it was strange since I could access the WP API just fine via browser, it turns out the only thing needed was adding an entry in the hosts file for the domain with the local IP. Everything worked after that.

Answer (score 1):

Can you ping `www.mysite.com` ?

Check your /etc/hosts ... maybe there is a wrong IP specified for `www.mysite.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well on a remote webserver. Running curl on this machine I wasn't able to access files hosted by an apache server on the same machine. Strange this was I could access file by

```
curl -O http://example.com/file1.txt
```

but

```
curl -0 http://sub.example.com/file1.txt
```

did not work.

I solved it by adding the missing DNS record to the DNS server running on the machine. Seems like `nslookup` etc first have a look at the local DNS server before asking somebody else. And as the local DNS server replied with "can't find" `curl` gave up.